# Very long TTFB and high CPU on VPS after Hypervisor Migration

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, centos, php, vps

I manage a VPS for my company with a small e-commerce website and a few low-usage Wordpress blogs and the like.

My Service Provider migrated me to a different Hypervisor last Thursday, and since then I have had huge problems with high TTFB on my sites, particularly the e-commerce site which now takes >10s to respond to a request.

The CPU seems to be much more stressed than it was, with PHP taking up the nearly all of it.  I have added extra CPU and RAM which has brought that down (although it really shouldn't have needed it - it's a small site and has been running perfectly smoothly for many months), but the TTFB problems remain.

I can see nothing unusual in logs for MySQL, PHP or Apache, and my provider insists that the Hypervisor is fine and the migration could not have caused my problems.  They correctly point at the fact that some of my software is slightly out of date (updating the server would mean a huge website refresh so I have it schedule in for the summer), but that was the case prior to the change as well, so it feels like a lazy answer.  I've included a graph to show the difference in CPU usage pre- and post-migration.

I am at a loss as to how to diagnose and fix the issue and would be grateful for suggestions.  The Server is running CentOS6.10 with cPanel v76 and PHP5

[CPU graph pre and post migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai1Wz.jpg)

Comment: Tell them to migrate you to some other hypervisor, then. Beyond that your choices are to go find another service provider.

Comment: They say they've migrated me to another hypervisor, to no effect.  I am indeed looking for another host but that's going to take weeks to move everything so I need a fix for the short term.

Comment: That _was_ the short term fix.